# How can I get a layout like this using flexbox?

Tags: html, layout, flexbox

I was practicing on my layouts using flexbox and was trying to make a layout like the one attached. I just can’t seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated. [layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8JRv.jpg)

Comment: Hi, I would try and help but this question will probably get shut down before I have a chance to write the code. Take a look here on how to ask questions on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

In the meantime, your solution is nesting flexboxes and mixing rows and columns. Take a look at this resource : https://www.quackit.com/css/flexbox/tutorial/nested_flex_containers.cfm

Comment: Thanks! But why would it get shutdown ? Sorry, new to using stack overflow. I looked at the tour link you sent but don’t see why they would shut it down.

Comment: Not enough information, no code example, this will be seen as low effort by most of the stack overflow community. You can edit your post to add more information. Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is indeed considered very low effort. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Show us your attempts and where you get stuck and then we can push you in the right direction.

Comment: Understood.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this question being pretty low quality, It is a Sunday and I need some CSS practice, here is my solution, anyone more experienced please feel free to edit or add some suggestions.

View in full page for actual result as in the image.

```css
    .flex-master {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            border-style: solid;
            border: 10px solid;
            height: 60%;
            width: 80%;
            
        }

        .flex-1 {
            flex: 6;
            border: 2px solid;
        }

        .flex-2 {
            display: flex;
            flex: 6;
            border: 2px solid;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .flex-3 {
            flex: 9;
            border: 2px solid;
        }

        .flex-4 {
            flex: 3;
            display: flex;
            border: 2px solid;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;   
        }

        .flex-5 {
            flex: 2;
            border: 2px solid;
        }

        .flex-6 {
            flex: 10;
            border: 2px solid;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="flex-master">
            <div class="flex-1">
                <h1>Red Dress Image</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-2">
                <div class="flex-3">
                    <h1>A Red Dress</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-4">
                    <div class="flex-5">
                        <h1>100k Customers</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex-6">
                        <h1>New Collection</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```